# HighCharts: How to Determine on Click Event what Data Grouping the Chart is Currently In?

Tags: highcharts

I've got data currently grouping by day, week and month using HighCharts.  I've also got a click event tied to the chart as well as each series.  When someone clicks, how can I determine what data grouping it's currently using - day, week, or month?

Here's a simplified example: http://jsfiddle.net/V5hSd/4/

Comment: Just updated with fiddle link, it's simplified but at least demonstrates what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Wow what a sport you are!! You choose a less detailed answer that was also posted after mine and gives the same solution. Be a sport dude

Comment: @JugalThakkar: It happens dude. I saw that you have answered user's last 4-5 questions. You keep up the spirit. :)

Comment: Thanks, truly appreciate your gesture. I am trying my best to keep it up :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this helps: http://jsfiddle.net/WRsyG/

Answer (score 4):

```
//If in chart's click event handler
this.series[i].currentDataGrouping.unitName

//If in series's event handler
this.currentDataGrouping.unitName
```

**HOW TO FIREBUG YOUR WAY TO THE SOLUTION**
Highchart has a nice readable object graph that tells you most the things without needing documentation. I strongly recommend firebug or developer tools of whichever browser you use

All that was needed was to set a breakpoint in the click handler, look through the locals, and see what makes sense for the problem in hand, and there you go.
You have (From the series's click handler) `this.currentDataGrouping.unitName`.

Now ain't that intutive?!!
[image]

Due apologies if I sounded rude, but I believe in empowering people in ways that help them solve their own problems the next time

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, wasn't looking for a spoon feeding, just a nudge in the right direction.  I did use Firebug, but when you start at a high level and try to trace it, there's so much data it's hard to know where to start drilling down.  I figured if someone had done it before, they would have a starting point.  You always have the option of not answering.  Your help is appreciate though.

Comment: like i said i don't mind answering as long as it helps somebody, was just showing you how I approached the problem in hand to reach to the solution so you could do similar stuff in future. Anyway lets not get into any argument. Sleep time in my country :) GN

Comment: @Dexter "wasn't looking for a spoon feeding, just a nudge in the right direction" were you being sarcastic? Coz you accepted an answer that did exactly that (spoon feed you into your fiddle). And can you share what exactly *did* you try? how deep can it be to drill down to this.currentDataGrouping is just beyond my understanding, so please enlighten me

Comment: nope, was actually serious, just felt his answer came with less drama.  If you're more concerned with empowering, the accepted answer shouldn't matter right?  Have a good one.

Comment: very true, but i also believe i ethics, which obviously doesn't ring a bell to you... 
good bye, fare well, adieu